# I can't print char array's elements with for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char usernames[5][10] = {"Lebron","Davis","Schroder","KCP","Gasol"};
  int i = 0;
  for(i=0; i < 20; i++) {
      printf("%s\n",usernames[i][20]);
 }}
```

Hello guys, I'm new at programming and I study for use for loop with char arrays. You can see my code in top.  The output I want to print is;

```
Lebron
Davis
Schroder
KCP
Gasol
```

I put my i into char's second dimension, is it not true? Basically, I want to print all the elements in my array, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `printf("%s\n",usernames[i]);` is what you want. Keep in mind that your array only has 5 items in it. Once you go past 4 in your loop you've entered undefined behavior land.

Comment: There seems to be plenty of misunderstandings about how arrays works in your code. Please take a step back, open your text-book and read more about arrays and array indexes.

Comment: It really worked but how C understood which elements I want to print? Can't I print these elements char by char?

Comment: To begin with for any ***valid*** index `i` and `j`, then `usernames[i][j]` is a *single character*, not a string.

Comment: I understood sir, thanks. How can I mark the answers as true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are storing data into 2d array. So, each row will store a sequence of char or a string . like usernames[0] = "Lebron" and so on. So, array length will be 5 . But you are trying to print 20 elements. that will give you runtime error.

here is the solution that will work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char usernames[5][10] = {"Lebron","Davis","Schroder","KCP","Gasol"};
  int i = 0;
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      printf("%s\n",usernames[i]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir that was so explanatory. But I have another question. How can I print these names char by char? Should I define another variable and write "printf("%c\n",usernames[i][j]" or something like this?

Comment: you need a nested loop for that. and print each character .

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char usernames[5][10] = {"Lebron","Davis","Schroder","KCP","Gasol"};
  int i = 0;
  int j=0;
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      for(j=0; j < sizeof(usernames[i]); j++){
        printf("%c\n",usernames[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return 0;
}